# Equivalent of `CrossVersion.for2_13Use3` for `dependsOn()` subproject that can't support Scala 3

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

In a [multi-project build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html), where there is a `legacy` sub-project that is on Scala 2.13 and can not yet be upgraded to Scala 3, can other Scala 3 projects in the same build depend on the `legacy` project and indicate that they want to use the Scala 2.13 version of it, as they would with [`CrossVersion.for2_13Use3`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html#a-scala-3-module-can-depend-on-a-scala-213-artifact) for a library dependency?

```scala
lazy val appServer = project.in(file("app-server"))
  .dependsOn(common, legacy)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `lazy val appServer = project.settings(scalaVersion := "3.2.1").dependsOn(legacy)` `lazy val legacy = project.settings(scalaVersion := "2.13.10")`?

Comment: There is Scala 2.13 - Scala 3 interop https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

@dmytro-mitin is completely right, it just works!

```scala
lazy val legacy = project.settings(scalaVersion := "2.13.10")
lazy val appServer = project.settings(scalaVersion := "3.2.1").dependsOn(legacy)
```

I tried it out with https://github.com/rtyley/multi-project-build-mixing-scala-3-and-scala-2 to [verify it worked](https://github.com/rtyley/multi-project-build-mixing-scala-3-and-scala-2/actions/runs/3534002510/jobs/5930359091#step:5:21).

This is documented in https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html#the-scala-3-unpickler

Comment: If you have 2.13 depending on 3, don't forget to use `-Ytasty-reader`. Also sometimes useful for 3 is `-Xignore-scala2-macros`.